# Find Region of Interest

Tags: image-processing

To draw shirt-width line, I need to find the armpit points (see pictures in these links:

1. [Picture 1](http://www.mediafire.com/view/zkhuo7kvl4obp/LVTN#dwk2dwgbve1at25)
2. [Picture 2](http://www.mediafire.com/view/zkhuo7kvl4obp/LVTN#t04aa0d12vwsgpx)

My idea is first to try to find the region that contents the armpit point, later use Haris algorithm to find that armpit point. Is it OK to do that? And if that is OK, what algorithms could be used? I think of Haar-like features. Another one could be Zone Features ([in Zone feature section](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238114/Realtime-Webcam-Sudoku-Solver)).

Comment: I think you can use morphological operators for finding the armpit region and point.

Comment: morphological operators (dilation, erosion, opening, closing...) couldn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the algorithms you mention might be an overkill for the simple task.

Like @blackSmith said, morphological operators would work and are a good idea:

Once you extracted the binary (and performing a flood fill if you have only a contour like in the first pic), you can perform a closing, and then subtract the original binary from it. Choose a morphological operator so that the points remaining are only the small angles of the armpits.

It's really that simple, here some pseudo code:

```
TestImage=Threshold(TestImage,0.3)
```

[image]

```
strel1=strel('square',25); // Create some structural elements. 25x25, very big!

strel2=strel('disk',25); // A circular element is good to close corners

TestImage=imopen(TestImage,strel1); //Gets rid of smaller particles

OpenImage=imopen(TestImage,strel2); //Closes the corners=>armpits

AddLayer=(TestImage-OpenImage); //Mark corners on original image

strel3=strel('disk',9);

AddLayer=imclose(AddLayer,strel3); //get rid of smaller areas

AddLayer=imdilate(AddLayer,strel3); //Not necessary but makes my point clearer
```

[image]

```
TestImageO(:,:,1)=TestImageO(:,:,1)+255*AddLayer; // Mark it on the original image
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is not that simple. How about this http://www.mediafire.com/view/zkhuo7kvl4obp/LVTN#dqu7nooosf84q6d

Comment: I'm not sure what your image means, but the MorphOps are very simple, take a look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I am thinking of how to tell the computer where the armpit is..

Comment: After did a lot of test, I found that the region mark the armpit has some clearly constant shape, so I think of using template matching. Is it OK?

Comment: You could use that, but it is probably easier to measure the area, or use it as a mask to run a corner detector; SUSAN has a very simple implementation.

Comment: OK, thank you McMa. About measure the area, I'm afraid that it couldn't. Because there is another shirt that doesn't create the corner mark the biggest area. Could you tell me a little more about how to use it as a mask to run a corner detector and what (who) is the SUSAN (I'm a newbie)

Comment: sure, no problem. About the mask: AddLayer is a binary matrix the same size as your image. So if you have a pixel operation (feature detector) on the pixel TestImage(i,j) of the original image, you can "mask" it by only performing the operation if AddLayer(i,j)==1. The Smallest Univalue segment blahblah... (SUSAN)  is a corner detector that runs a tiny "circle" over the image , if the intensity of the centre pixel repeats itself x times inside the rest of the circle then you have a corner. Read about it on wikipedia.